# Mongo-Driver Should I use InsertMany or InsertOne

Tags: mongodb, rest, go

I am creating a Rest CRUD HTTP server written in Go. My error is I am getting this message from the database connection: "context deadline exceeded".

I have a `CreateUsers()` function to insert multiple users into the database. Currently, I am inserting one user at time:

```golang
func CreateUsers(users []*models.User) ([]primitive.ObjectID, error) {
    client, ctx, cancel := database.GetConnection()
    defer cancel()
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
    var userIds []primitive.ObjectID

    if len(users) == 0 {
        log.Printf("No users to create")
        return userIds, errors.New("no users to create")
    }

    for _, user := range users {
        user.ID = primitive.NewObjectID()

        hashedPassword, err := utils.HashPassword(user.Password)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error while hashing password: %v", err)
            return userIds, err
        }
        user.Password = hashedPassword

        result, err := client.Database("users").Collection("users").InsertOne(ctx, user)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error while creating user: %v", err)
            return userIds, err
        }

        oid := result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)
        userIds = append(userIds, oid)
    }

    return userIds, nil
}
```

My database connection (`database.GetConnection)` is something like:

```golang
func GetConnection() (*mongo.Client, context.Context, context.CancelFunc) {
    client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(connectionURI))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error while creating client: %v", err)
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), connectionTimeout*time.Second)

    err = client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cluster connection error: %v", err)
    }

    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cluster ping error")
    }

    log.Println("connected to mongodb")
    return client, ctx, cancel
}
```

> Note: `connectionTimeout` is equal to `5`.

I am not sure but the time exceeded error may be related to the `InsertOne()` approach. So, instead of focusing in solving that error I should be asking how to parse the `[]models.User` into `bson.D{}` documents to pass them as parameters to `InsertMany()`.

I think another advantage of using `InsertMany` approach is the query time will be way below. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try running the query from the mongo shell and see if it takes > 5s? If it does then there's an issue in your code :)

Comment: @Wolfgang, thank you for the suggestion. I have seen that the users were inserted into the database. Thus the error occurs after that. So , I still have to think how to use the `InsertMany()` approach.